# Adding a variable into a a path in django

Tags: python, django

I am making my first website in Django but my tutorial was created long ago. I need to add the variable question_id into the following path:

```
path('<question_id [0-9]>/',views.detail, name = "detail")
```

the function detail looks like this:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse('Leo is the best')
```

This is what the error looks like:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:


polls/ [name='index']
polls/ <question_id = [0-9]>/ [name='detail']
polls/ <question_id>[0-9]/result [name='result']
polls/ <question_id>[0-9]/vote [name='vote']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, rather than using a tutorial "created a long time ago", you should use the actual tutorial for your Django version.

The code you have used in your URLs is neither valid for the old regex-based routing nor for the new-style path routing. The new style is easier, you should probably just use that:

```
path('<int:question_id>/',views.detail, name = "detail")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `r'^<question_id [0-9]>$'` instead of `<question_id [0-9]>/` and as far as I know, correct syntax for Django is `url(r'^<question_id [0-9]>$',views.detail, name = "detail")` not path.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but you should use `url()` not `path()`